# UIView with UIScrollView as a subclass not receiving touch events

Tags: ios

I am having UIView with touches begin/moved/ended methods.I have added UIScrollView as a subview for the UIView.Now I am not receiving any touch events in those touch corresponding methods after adding UIScrollView as a subview.I tried setting the UIScrollView properties  canCancelContentTouches, delaysContentTouches to NO.But still it is not working.

Comment: You could set the scrollview to `setUserInteractionEnabled:NO` and handle the scrollview scrolling in your UIView touch events.  But otherwise if the scrollview's contentsize is larger than it's frame it will consume the touch events.

Answer (score 1):

You can override UIView methods:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Determine if the touch is within the bounds of subview (scrollview) and pass them to your parent view

```
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

and

```
return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
```

Comment: But the problem here is bounds of both the UIView and UIScrollView are same.